# Optimizing code structure for ViewHolder members - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a ViewHolder that looks something like this:

```
class ViewHolder(
        itemView: View,
        var mSettingsRadioButton: RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(...),
        var mSettingsCheckBox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(...),
        var mSettingsChevron: Icon = itemView.findViewById(...)
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

The idea is to make the the other two invisible when one of them is active, i.e. if a checkbox is active, the chevron and radio button should be invisible.

Right now I am using 3 functions for this purpose something like this:

```
fun setCheckbox(viewHolder: ViewHolder) {
        viewHolder.apply {
            mSettingsChevron.visibility = GONE
            mSettingsRadioButton.visibility = GONE
            mSettingsCheckBox.let {
                it.visibility = VISIBLE
                it.isChecked = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Although this approach works, I have 3 functions that are practically doing the same thing. I am looking for much cleaner and optimized way of writing this functionality. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with just that.  You could give the icon and radio button a common parent so you can set the visibility there, but that would actually hurt your drawing performance by increasing depth needlessly.  This is pretty much optimal.  You could move code around in various abstractions, but in the end two of the views have to be set to GONE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only one function you could, and it would remove redundant code so you would be achieving DRY principle.

```
fun setVisibility(isCheckBoxVisible: Boolean, isRadioButtonVisible: Boolean, isChevronVisible: Boolean) {
    mSettingsCheckBox.visibility = if (isCheckBoxVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    mSettingsRadioButton.visibility = if (isRadioButtonVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    mSettingsChevron.visibility = if (isChevronVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

And now you would just call `setVisibility` accordingly

```
// Show only the checkbox
viewHolder.setVisibility(true, false, false)

// Show only the radio button
viewHolder.setVisibility(false, true, false)

// Show only the chevron
viewHolder.setVisibility(false, false, true)

// And if you need
// Hide all views
viewHolder.setVisibility(false, false, false)
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks much better

Comment: There's a [Jetpack extension property](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.view/android.view.-view/is-visible.html) that further simplifies this. For example, you can use `mSettingscheckBox.isVisible = isCheckBoxVisible` in the function above.